# circular byte shifting in an array

Tags: matrix, byte, led, basic

I'm coding an LED display (7x48) and the language I'm working in is BASIC (no former experience in that language, but in C/C++) and I have a small issue.
I have an array (red[20] of byte) and an example of a current state is:
to make it easier here lets say its red[3]

10011010  01011100  01011101

and now i need to shift the array by 1 so in next cycle its supposed to be

00110100  10111000  10111011

so what happened is that the whole array shifted for 1 bit to left

the BASIC I'm working with doesn't have any .NET APIs so I need the total low level code (doesn't have to be BASIC, I can translate it, I just need an idea how to do it as I'm limited to 8KB code memory so I have to fully optmize it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use bit shift operations:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d9yb87a.aspx

Let `x` be the element you want to shift:

```
x = (x<<1) | (x>>23)
```

or in general, if you want to shift left by `y` bits and there are a total of `n` bits:

```
x = (x<<y) | (x>>(n-y))
```

I don't know basic well, but here's what I would do in a C++/Java/C# language:

Assuming you have red[] of length n:

```
int b = 32; //Number of bits per byte (your example showed 24, but usually there are 32)
int y = 1; //Number of bytes to shift to the left
int carry = 0;  //The bytes to carry over (I'm assuming that they move up the array from red[0] to red[1], etc.

for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    int newCarry = (red[i]>>(n-y));
    red[i] = (red[i]<<y) | carry;
    carry = newCarry;
}

//Complete the loop
red[0]|=carry;
```

Comment: yes im aware of those but does basic support some kind of carry? i need to transport the value from red[2] to the last bit of red[1] for instance.

Comment: im still not sure how you passed the values from element to element? like if red[1] is 0xFF and red[2] is 0x00, after the << shift i need red[1] to be 0xFE and red[2] 0x01 (if the array size is 2)

Comment: ohhh I misunderstood. I'll update my solution. Are you allowed to make a new copy of the array?

Comment: yes, but im programming a 16 bit PIC so im limited on memory, tho my old solution had 3 arrays and a lot of code, if you could figure the best way that you can it would be awesome.

Comment: Updated my answer to use an array in place.

Comment: still not working... i tried it in C# (tho i had to convert all ints to byte since PicBasic doesnt support integer) 
http://pokit.org/get/?ca10246e30af616e2e525edb5c610b8f.jpg

and i added 2 loops to write the array before and after your code.

Comment: nvm my mistake on first screenshot, i had a very stupid mistake at the second loop, this is the screenshot of the new output
http://pokit.org/get/img/a0658835fb1437e1f94e435e66d5c1de.jpg

Comment: oh... it looks like it works actually, im tired and didnt really notice what i was doing... thx in any case!

Comment: no... here's the screenshot from my C# attempt 
http://pokit.org/get/?44a2b7430913ed4c50e3d6d58b0a0a40.jpg
and my basic translated code:
http://pokit.org/get/img/ec9fd507cbf66966b9a360333b0fdc6f.jpg

tho in the basic translated code i all LED's turn on (which means that all elements of the array are 0xFF )

Comment: and this is a pic of the actual display so you get the picture on how it should work, 1 row is 1 array ( red1 for example ) and i want text to move from one side to another and reappear at the end (loop), thats what this is all about.
http://pokit.org/get/img/0bc3ec1ab6017afe32d3ff03990fbebc.jpg

Comment: figured it out! I just changed your line:
int newCarry = (red[i]>>(n-y));

into


newCarry = (Byte)(red[i]>>7);

it shifts now perfect! thanks.

Comment: tho the last bit wont move into the first bit of the array Q _ Q

Comment: Did you include the red[0]|=carry; line?

Comment: i fixed it, looks like i got a documentation for a newer version of the compiler i currently have (or i just dont know basic, which i dont) I thought OR is the | in this compiler but seems like OR doesnt work for bitwise operations. Luckily | works and the display is scrolling properly!Thanks again

Comment: sweet. If you think my answer was helpful, you should accept it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
If most significant bit is 1:
    subtract value of most significant bit
    multiply by 2 
    add 1
otherwise:
    multiply by 2
```